Doctrine : How to manage tables with entities and other tables manually?
I have an application with database manage by doctrine with entities.
My application need to create tables dynamically without entity. (Programmatically)
When I execute doctrine:schema:update command, tables create dynamically are dropped.
If I add
#schema_filter: ~^(?!g_)~ 

To dbal configuration, doctrine:schema:update ignore my tables. It's good.
On the other hand, when I use:
$currentSchema = $sm->introspectSchema();
    $newSchema = clone $currentSchema;
    $table =  $newSchema->getTable('g_cars');
    $table->addColumn("zoby", "string", []);

getTable not found my table (manage by myself, not by doctrine).
How can I keep the entities managed by doctrine and my tables created in programming using the SchemaManager?
Should we override the doctrine:schema:update command?

Just for your information: Creating tables dynamically is almost always the wrong thing to do. There are always better solutions.

Why is the wrong thing to do ?
My users need to create differents contents from my app.

The need to create different contents doesn't mean you need to create new tables. Here are some posts about this topic: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/238235/dynamic-or-static-database-tables https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5999756/why-creating-tables-in-run-time-code-behind-is-bad https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/382440/does-it-ever-make-sense-to-create-tables-dynamically https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/42366/is-it-a-good-practice-to-create-tables-dynamically-in-a-site

I solved my problem.
For those who are interested, i have build my own doctrine:schema:update command.
My command, introspect the schema from database.
I build another schema from doctrine entities and my custom logic.
I compare difference between schema thank to SchemaTool.
In result, i have SQL queries to execute for synchronize my database schema.
I hope this can help someone who has had the same problem.
